# How does Appcelerator Analytics get user's geographic location without using Location Service?

Tags: analytics, appcelerator

[Appcelerator Analytics Docs](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_Analytics)

> By default, it provides the number of applications installs, the number of sessions, and the average application session length organized by application name, platform and **geography.**

If I go to the Dashboard, there is indeed geographical data. I'm sure my app doesn't use Location Service on both Android and iOS. How does Appcelerator get the geographical data? By IP?

Comment: Yes, I also think so that it takes location based on IP address as I read it somewhere but unfortunately I cannot remember it currently. I will add that link when I remember it.

Comment: Are you trying to reproduce this feature in your own app?

Comment: Right. I want to detect user's location without relying on location service.